# Which law of polynomials does this follow from ? Any insight is appreciated

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$a(x-6)^4 + b(x-6)^3 + c(x-6)^2 + d(x-6) = 0$$

Without explicitly expanding the left side of the equation above, we can see that the left side has a $ax^4$ term. Because the right side has no $x^4$ term, this implies that $a = 0$. I’m confused how one can deduce this from that.

Comment: what equation? I don't see any equation

Comment: There is no equation above.

Comment: Two polynomials are equal if and only if they have the same degree and the same coefficients for each term. Since the right-hand side is the zero polynomial, you know that all coefficients on the left must also be zero.

Comment: If this is meant to be an equality of polynomials, you’d be right. But that is doubtful. It could be an equation seeking a solution for $x$: that is, the values of $x$ for which the equality holds.  For instance, it is plain that $x=6$ is a solution...